# How can I get the value from the normal select in .net c# web application?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I get the value from the normal select in .net c# web application?

Example:

If I have a code as below:

```
<Select ID="test" name="test">
  <option value ="1">One</option>
  <option value ="2">Two</option>
  <option value ="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

and this is my .net c# code:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    team.CampaignID = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["test"]);
}
```

but it doesn't seem working for me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking the wrong collection; you should be checking the Form NameValueCollection:

```
Request.Form["test"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `runat="server"` on your `select` element, you can programatically access the control by ID in your code behind.